# Building python wheel via docker-compose on AWS EC2 gets stuck

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a docker container that builds fine on my laptop (iOS) and my PC (Ubuntu 20.4). I am trying to build it on AWS EC2 instance(Ubuntu 18.04) but it gets stuck at the following line while installing requirements.txt for python:

```
Building wheel for lxml (setup.py): started
```

It does not show an error just gets stuck. On my laptop/PC this bit takes about 2 minutes (which is longer than others that take much less). I've now been waiting for over 2 hours for this to finish, which kind of rules out performance issues (surely it can't be THAT slow?).

Docker-compose and docker versions are the same (latest) on all machines.

Any ideas what might be causing this, and how long it is reasonable to wait for? I thought docker should be independent of host, providing docker versions were the same.

Comment: which Ec2 instance type you are using?

Comment: t2.micro (free tier) for now, just testing out waters

Comment: better to open two ssh and during wheel build time check cpu usage with `top` and `watch free -m` seems like a memory issue or cpu issue

Comment: When building python wheels from Docker, 'top' shows that command 'cc1' uses 99%+ of CPU and 50+% of memory. After less than a minute or so it stops refreshing the data. (Free memory never goes lower than 60-70 while monitoring using watch free -m). It then becomes very difficult/impossible to connect to the instance. So, yes, seems like a CPU issue. Do you think that AWS free tier is not going to work for the purpose, or is there something else I can try?

Comment: I will recommend build image locally, push image to ECR and run image only, so you will able to run even with free tier, added as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discussion in the comment, the instance is small enough which hit **99% CPU usage** and **60-70% Memory usage** so instance becomes unresponsive.

So possible two option that you can try

- Move all **build task to docker image and build the image locally and push the image to [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/)** and just run the docker image over Ec2 instead of building docker image or wheel on Ec2 machine.

By doing this you will be able to run your application with **t2.micro by taking advantage from free tier.**

Or

- Upgrade instance some higher specs, which have more VCPU, if t2.micro does not work, then possibly `t2.small` instance will work.